# Permission denied in jenkins

Tags: centos, permissions, jenkins

I am trying to run a shell script in jenkins and have given all permissions on the file.

On the run, jenkins mentions the below error

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test
[Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2660493526195024199.sh
+ /home/admin/Scripts/attest.sh
/tmp/jenkins2660493526195024199.sh: line 2: /home/admin/Scripts/attest.sh: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The file permissions are

```
[root@prod-server Scripts]# getfacl attest.sh 
# file: attest.sh
# owner: jenkins
# group: jenkins
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

I am failing to understand why the file is not accessible even though when the file has full permissions. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Check if your /home filesystem is mounted as `noexec`

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct

`mount | grep -i /home/` shows nothing

Comment: `ls -ld / /home /home/admin /home/admin/Scripts /home/admin/Scripts/attest.sh` please. I suspect one (or more) of those is missing the necessary permissions.

Comment: Are there any (related) AVC denial messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Recently had a very similar problem with jenkins. Check whether user jenkins has executable access rights on each file in the absolute filepath.
That is home, admin, Scripts should as well be available for execution for user jenkins. In case these directories are not owned by jenkins and
owned by a group to which jenkins is not added, executable permissions should be granted to other users. Or you can add jenkins to group that owns the file.
However, in such case you will have to restart jenkins server in order to reload configuration with new group access for user jenkins.

Comment: Voters: More like a "maybe this" - type, but I think it is clearly not VLQ candidate.

Comment: I suggested this too (but as a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379184/permission-denied-in-jenkins#comment828476_379184)). The OP didn't bother to come back.